# Opencart pagination links on search results just reload first page when clicked, and adds "#" to the URL String

Tags: search, pagination, hyperlink, opencart, broken-links

When I submit search results on my site it loads accurate results with the correct number of products displayed... When I go down to the pagination links at the bottom they show the correct links when hovered over them... However when I click on them it just reloads the page I'm  already at AND it adds # to the end of the URL string.... The code appears to be correct, my initial feeling is that this maybe because of the SEO URLS I have enabled in opencart, and the HTACCESS edits I have made....

Here is an example: http://www.justicejewelers.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=gold

HTACCESS:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Search.php:

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->total = $product_total;
$pagination->page = $page;
$pagination->limit = $limit;
$pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');
```

Search.TPL:

```
    <?php echo $header; ?>

<?php echo $content_top; ?>



<div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>">
            <?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<header class="heading">
    <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
    <div id="notification"></div>
</header>

<?php 

if ($column_left || $column_right) { $main = "span9"; } 
else {  $main = "span12"; } 

?>  

<div class="row-fluid">

    <?php echo $column_left; ?>

    <section id="maincontent" class="<?php echo $main; ?> search listing" role="main">

        <div class="mainborder">

            <?php if ($column_left) { ?>
                <div id="toggle_sidebar"></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="search-criteria">

                <div class="contentset center">
                    <h4 class="inner">
                        <span><?php echo $text_critea; ?></span>
                    </h4>
                </div>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="search" name="filter_name" id="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" class="search-box span6" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>

                <select name="filter_category_id" class="filter-category span4">

                    <option value="0"><?php echo $text_category; ?></option>

                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>

                        <?php if ($category_1['category_id'] == $filter_category_id) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>

                            <?php if ($category_2['category_id'] == $filter_category_id) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
                                <?php if ($category_3['category_id'] == $filter_category_id) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <?php } ?>

                    <?php } ?>

                </select>

                <div class="controls">

                    <label class="checkbox inline">

                        <?php if ($filter_sub_category) { ?>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="filter_sub_category" value="1" id="sub_category" checked="checked" />
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="filter_sub_category" value="1" id="sub_category" />
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php echo $text_sub_category; ?>

                    </label>

                    <label class="checkbox inline">

                        <?php if ($filter_description) { ?>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="filter_description" value="1" id="description" checked="checked" />
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="filter_description" value="1" id="description" />
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php echo $entry_description; ?>

                    </label>

                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_search; ?>" id="button-search" class="btn btn-inverse" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="contentset center">
                <h4 class="inner">
                    <span><?php echo $text_search; ?></span>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Products 
            ============================== -->

            <?php if ($products) { ?>

                <!-- Grid/Lis view, filters 
                ============================== -->

                <div class="product-filter">

                    <div class="btn-group display" data-toggle="buttons-radio">

                        <button id="grid" class="btn btn-mini" title="<?php echo $text_grid; ?>" onclick="display('grid');"><i class="icon-th"></i></button>

                        <button id="list" class="btn btn-mini" title="<?php echo $text_list; ?>" onclick="display('list');"><i class="icon-list"></i></button>

                    </div>

                    <span class="product-compare"><a href="<?php echo $compare; ?>" id="compare-total"><?php echo $text_compare; ?></a></span>

                    <div class="list-options"> 

                        <div class="sort">

                            <?php echo $text_sort; ?>

                            <select onchange="location = this.value;">
                                <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
                                <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>

                        </div>

                        <div class="limit">

                            <?php echo $text_limit; ?>

                            <select onchange="location = this.value;">

                                <?php foreach ($limits as $limits) { ?>

                                    <?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>

                                        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected">
                                            <?php echo $limits['text']; ?>
                                        </option>

                                    <?php } else { ?>

                                        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $limits['text']; ?>
                                        </option>

                                    <?php } ?>

                                <?php } ?>

                            </select>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Product list (Default to Grid) 
                ============================== -->

                <div class="product-grid row-fluid">

                    <?php 

                    $counter=0;

                    foreach ($products as $product) { 

                        if ($counter == 0 ) $xclass = 'alpha';
                        else if (($counter+12) % 12 == 0 ) $xclass = 'alpha4 alpha3';
                        else if (($counter+4) % 4 == 0 ) $xclass = 'alpha4';
                        else if (($counter+3) % 3 == 0 ) $xclass = 'alpha3';
                        else $xclass = '';

                        if (($counter+2) % 2 == 0 ) $xclass .= ' odd';

                    ?>

                    <div class="grid-box <?php echo $xclass; ?>">

                        <div class="inner">

                            <?php if ($product['price'] && $product['special']) { ?>
                                <span class="onsale">
                                    <?php $this->language->load('module/sellegance');
                                    echo $this->language->get('text_onsale'); ?>
                                </span>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="name">
                                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
                            </div>

                            <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <img src="catalog/view/theme/sellegance/images/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" />
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>

                            <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>

                                <div class="price">

                                    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                                        <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                                        <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
                                        <br />
                                        <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>

                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="actions">

                                <div class="cart">
                                    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="btn btn-cart btn-small" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>

                                <div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <?php $counter++; } ?>

                </div> <!-- .produc-grid -->

                <div class="paginate"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <div class="content empty white">

                    <div class="alert warning"><?php echo $text_empty; ?><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a></div>

                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    </section><!-- #maincontent -->

    <?php echo $column_right; ?>

</div> <!-- .row -->

<?php echo $content_bottom; ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 


    jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_name\']').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            jQuery('.button-search').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    jQuery('#button-search').bind('click', function() {
        url = 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var filter_name = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
        }

        var filter_category_id = jQuery('#maincontent select[name=\'filter_category_id\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_category_id > 0) {
            url += '&filter_category_id=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_category_id);
        }

        var filter_sub_category = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_sub_category\']:checked').attr('value');

        if (filter_sub_category) {
            url += '&filter_sub_category=true';
        }

        var filter_description = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_description\']:checked').attr('value');

        if (filter_description) {
            url += '&filter_description=true';
        }

        location = url;

    });

</script>
```

The true question is why would this script in search:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_name\']').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            jQuery('.button-search').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    jQuery('#button-search').bind('click', function() {
        url = 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var filter_name = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
        }

        var filter_category_id = jQuery('#maincontent select[name=\'filter_category_id\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_category_id > 0) {
            url += '&filter_category_id=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_category_id);
        }

        var filter_sub_category = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_sub_category\']:checked').attr('value');

        if (filter_sub_category) {
            url += '&filter_sub_category=true';
        }

        var filter_description = jQuery('#maincontent input[name=\'filter_description\']:checked').attr('value');

        if (filter_description) {
            url += '&filter_description=true';
        }

        location = url;

    });

</script>
```

BE effected by bannerpack, and not work without it?

Here is the code for Banner Pack:

```
    (function($){var NivoSlider=function(element,options){var settings=$.extend({},$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults,options);var vars={currentSlide:0,currentImage:'',totalSlides:0,randAnim:'',running:false,paused:false,stop:false};var slider=$(element);slider.data('nivo:vars',vars);slider.css('position','relative');slider.addClass('nivoSlider');var kids=slider.children();kids.each(function(){var child=$(this);var link='';if(!child.is('img')){if(child.is('a')){child.addClass('nivo-imageLink');link=child;}
child=child.find('img:first');}
var childWidth=child.width();if(childWidth==0)childWidth=child.attr('width');var childHeight=child.height();if(childHeight==0)childHeight=child.attr('height');if(childWidth>slider.width()){slider.width(childWidth);}
if(childHeight>slider.height()){slider.height(childHeight);}
if(link!=''){link.css('display','none');}
child.css('display','none');vars.totalSlides++;});if(settings.startSlide>0){if(settings.startSlide>=vars.totalSlides)settings.startSlide=vars.totalSlides-1;vars.currentSlide=settings.startSlide;}
if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){vars.currentImage=$(kids[vars.currentSlide]);}else{vars.currentImage=$(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');}
if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){$(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');}
slider.css('background','url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat');slider.append($('<div class="nivo-caption"><p></p></div>').css({display:'none',opacity:settings.captionOpacity}));var processCaption=function(settings){var nivoCaption=$('.nivo-caption',slider);if(vars.currentImage.attr('title')!=''&&vars.currentImage.attr('title')!=undefined){var title=vars.currentImage.attr('title');if(title.substr(0,1)=='#')title=$(title).html();if(nivoCaption.css('display')=='block'){nivoCaption.find('p').fadeOut(settings.animSpeed,function(){$(this).html(title);$(this).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);});}else{nivoCaption.find('p').html(title);}
nivoCaption.fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);}else{nivoCaption.fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);}}
processCaption(settings);var timer=0;if(!settings.manualAdvance&&kids.length>1){timer=setInterval(function(){nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,false);},settings.pauseTime);}
if(settings.directionNav){slider.append('<div class="ban_direction"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+settings.prevText+'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+settings.nextText+'</a></div>');if(settings.directionNavHide){$('.ban_direction',slider).hide();slider.hover(function(){$('.ban_direction',slider).show();},function(){$('.ban_direction',slider).hide();});}
$('a.nivo-prevNav',slider).live('click',function(){if(vars.running)return false;clearInterval(timer);timer='';vars.currentSlide-=2;nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,'prev');});$('a.nivo-nextNav',slider).live('click',function(){if(vars.running)return false;clearInterval(timer);timer='';nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,'next');});}
if(settings.controlNav){var nivoControl=$('<div class="banner_control"></div>');slider.append(nivoControl);for(var i=0;i<kids.length;i++){if(settings.controlNavThumbs){var child=kids.eq(i);if(!child.is('img')){child=child.find('img:first');}
if(settings.controlNavThumbsFromRel){nivoControl.append('<a class="ban_control" rel="'+i+'"><img src="'+child.attr('rel')+'" alt="" /></a>');}else{nivoControl.append('<a class="ban_control" rel="'+i+'"><img src="'+child.attr('src').replace(settings.controlNavThumbsSearch,settings.controlNavThumbsReplace)+'" alt="" /></a>');}}else{nivoControl.append('<a class="ban_control" rel="'+i+'">'+(i+1)+'</a>');}}
$('.banner_control a:eq('+vars.currentSlide+')',slider).addClass('active');$('.banner_control a',slider).live('click',function(){if(vars.running)return false;if($(this).hasClass('active'))return false;clearInterval(timer);timer='';slider.css('background','url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat');vars.currentSlide=$(this).attr('rel')-1;nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,'control');});}
if(settings.keyboardNav){$(window).keypress(function(event){if(event.keyCode=='37'){if(vars.running)return false;clearInterval(timer);timer='';vars.currentSlide-=2;nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,'prev');}
if(event.keyCode=='39'){if(vars.running)return false;clearInterval(timer);timer='';nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,'next');}});}
if(settings.pauseOnHover){slider.hover(function(){vars.paused=true;clearInterval(timer);timer='';},function(){vars.paused=false;if(timer==''&&!settings.manualAdvance){timer=setInterval(function(){nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,false);},settings.pauseTime);}});}
slider.bind('nivo:animFinished',function(){vars.running=false;$(kids).each(function(){if($(this).is('a')){$(this).css('display','none');}});if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){$(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');}
if(timer==''&&!vars.paused&&!settings.manualAdvance){timer=setInterval(function(){nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,false);},settings.pauseTime);}
settings.afterChange.call(this);});var createSlices=function(slider,settings,vars){for(var i=0;i<settings.slices;i++){var sliceWidth=Math.round(slider.width()/settings.slices);if(i==settings.slices-1){slider.append($('<div class="banner-slice"></div>').css({left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px',width:(slider.width()-(sliceWidth*i))+'px',height:'0px',opacity:'0',background:'url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat -'+((sliceWidth+(i*sliceWidth))-sliceWidth)+'px 0%'}));}else{slider.append($('<div class="banner-slice"></div>').css({left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px',width:sliceWidth+'px',height:'0px',opacity:'0',background:'url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat -'+((sliceWidth+(i*sliceWidth))-sliceWidth)+'px 0%'}));}}}
var createBoxes=function(slider,settings,vars){var boxWidth=Math.round(slider.width()/settings.boxCols);var boxHeight=Math.round(slider.height()/settings.boxRows);for(var rows=0;rows<settings.boxRows;rows++){for(var cols=0;cols<settings.boxCols;cols++){if(cols==settings.boxCols-1){slider.append($('<div class="bannar-box"></div>').css({opacity:0,left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px',top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',width:(slider.width()-(boxWidth*cols))+'px',height:boxHeight+'px',background:'url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat -'+((boxWidth+(cols*boxWidth))-boxWidth)+'px -'+((boxHeight+(rows*boxHeight))-boxHeight)+'px'}));}else{slider.append($('<div class="bannar-box"></div>').css({opacity:0,left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px',top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',width:boxWidth+'px',height:boxHeight+'px',background:'url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat -'+((boxWidth+(cols*boxWidth))-boxWidth)+'px -'+((boxHeight+(rows*boxHeight))-boxHeight)+'px'}));}}}}
var nivoRun=function(slider,kids,settings,nudge){var vars=slider.data('nivo:vars');if(vars&&(vars.currentSlide==vars.totalSlides-1)){settings.lastSlide.call(this);}
if((!vars||vars.stop)&&!nudge)return false;settings.beforeChange.call(this);if(!nudge){slider.css('background','url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat');}else{if(nudge=='prev'){slider.css('background','url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat');}
if(nudge=='next'){slider.css('background','url("'+vars.currentImage.attr('src')+'") no-repeat');}}
vars.currentSlide++;if(vars.currentSlide==vars.totalSlides){vars.currentSlide=0;settings.slideshowEnd.call(this);}
if(vars.currentSlide<0)vars.currentSlide=(vars.totalSlides-1);if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){vars.currentImage=$(kids[vars.currentSlide]);}else{vars.currentImage=$(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');}
if(settings.controlNav){$('.banner_control a',slider).removeClass('active');$('.banner_control a:eq('+vars.currentSlide+')',slider).addClass('active');}
processCaption(settings);$('.banner-slice',slider).remove();$('.bannar-box',slider).remove();if(settings.effect=='random'){var anims=new Array('fade');vars.randAnim=anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length+1))];if(vars.randAnim==undefined)vars.randAnim='fade';}
if(settings.effect.indexOf(',')!=-1){var anims=settings.effect.split(',');vars.randAnim=anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length))];if(vars.randAnim==undefined)vars.randAnim='fade';}
vars.running=true;if(settings.effect=='sliceDown'||settings.effect=='sliceDownRight'||vars.randAnim=='sliceDownRight'||settings.effect=='sliceDownLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceDownLeft'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var timeBuff=0;var i=0;var slices=$('.banner-slice',slider);if(settings.effect=='sliceDownLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceDownLeft')slices=$('.banner-slice',slider)._reverse();slices.each(function(){var slice=$(this);slice.css({'top':'0px'});if(i==settings.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+timeBuff));}else{setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed);},(100+timeBuff));}
timeBuff+=50;i++;});}
else if(settings.effect=='sliceUp'||settings.effect=='sliceUpRight'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpRight'||settings.effect=='sliceUpLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpLeft'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var timeBuff=0;var i=0;var slices=$('.banner-slice',slider);if(settings.effect=='sliceUpLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpLeft')slices=$('.banner-slice',slider)._reverse();slices.each(function(){var slice=$(this);slice.css({'bottom':'0px'});if(i==settings.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+timeBuff));}else{setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed);},(100+timeBuff));}
timeBuff+=50;i++;});}
else if(settings.effect=='sliceUpDown'||settings.effect=='sliceUpDownRight'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpDown'||settings.effect=='sliceUpDownLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpDownLeft'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var timeBuff=0;var i=0;var v=0;var slices=$('.banner-slice',slider);if(settings.effect=='sliceUpDownLeft'||vars.randAnim=='sliceUpDownLeft')slices=$('.banner-slice',slider)._reverse();slices.each(function(){var slice=$(this);if(i==0){slice.css('top','0px');i++;}else{slice.css('bottom','0px');i=0;}
if(v==settings.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+timeBuff));}else{setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({height:'100%',opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed);},(100+timeBuff));}
timeBuff+=50;v++;});}
else if(settings.effect=='fold'||vars.randAnim=='fold'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var timeBuff=0;var i=0;$('.banner-slice',slider).each(function(){var slice=$(this);var origWidth=slice.width();slice.css({top:'0px',height:'100%',width:'0px'});if(i==settings.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({width:origWidth,opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+timeBuff));}else{setTimeout(function(){slice.animate({width:origWidth,opacity:'1.0'},settings.animSpeed);},(100+timeBuff));}
timeBuff+=50;i++;});}
else if(settings.effect=='fade'||vars.randAnim=='fade'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var firstSlice=$('.banner-slice:first',slider);firstSlice.css({'height':'100%','width':slider.width()+'px'});firstSlice.animate({opacity:'1.0'},(settings.animSpeed*2),'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});}
else if(settings.effect=='slideInRight'||vars.randAnim=='slideInRight'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var firstSlice=$('.banner-slice:first',slider);firstSlice.css({'height':'100%','width':'0px','opacity':'1'});firstSlice.animate({width:slider.width()+'px'},(settings.animSpeed*2),'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});}
else if(settings.effect=='slideInLeft'||vars.randAnim=='slideInLeft'){createSlices(slider,settings,vars);var firstSlice=$('.banner-slice:first',slider);firstSlice.css({'height':'100%','width':'0px','opacity':'1','left':'','right':'0px'});firstSlice.animate({width:slider.width()+'px'},(settings.animSpeed*2),'',function(){firstSlice.css({'left':'0px','right':''});slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});}
else if(settings.effect=='boxRandom'||vars.randAnim=='boxRandom'){createBoxes(slider,settings,vars);var totalBoxes=settings.boxCols*settings.boxRows;var i=0;var timeBuff=0;var boxes=shuffle($('.bannar-box',slider));boxes.each(function(){var box=$(this);if(i==totalBoxes-1){setTimeout(function(){box.animate({opacity:'1'},settings.animSpeed,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+timeBuff));}else{setTimeout(function(){box.animate({opacity:'1'},settings.animSpeed);},(100+timeBuff));}
timeBuff+=20;i++;});}
else if(settings.effect=='boxRain'||vars.randAnim=='boxRain'||settings.effect=='boxRainReverse'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainReverse'||settings.effect=='boxRainGrow'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainGrow'||settings.effect=='boxRainGrowReverse'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainGrowReverse'){createBoxes(slider,settings,vars);var totalBoxes=settings.boxCols*settings.boxRows;var i=0;var timeBuff=0;var rowIndex=0;var colIndex=0;var box2Darr=new Array();box2Darr[rowIndex]=new Array();var boxes=$('.bannar-box',slider);if(settings.effect=='boxRainReverse'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainReverse'||settings.effect=='boxRainGrowReverse'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainGrowReverse'){boxes=$('.bannar-box',slider)._reverse();}
boxes.each(function(){box2Darr[rowIndex][colIndex]=$(this);colIndex++;if(colIndex==settings.boxCols){rowIndex++;colIndex=0;box2Darr[rowIndex]=new Array();}});for(var cols=0;cols<(settings.boxCols*2);cols++){var prevCol=cols;for(var rows=0;rows<settings.boxRows;rows++){if(prevCol>=0&&prevCol<settings.boxCols){(function(row,col,time,i,totalBoxes){var box=$(box2Darr[row][col]);var w=box.width();var h=box.height();if(settings.effect=='boxRainGrow'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainGrow'||settings.effect=='boxRainGrowReverse'||vars.randAnim=='boxRainGrowReverse'){box.width(0).height(0);}
if(i==totalBoxes-1){setTimeout(function(){box.animate({opacity:'1',width:w,height:h},settings.animSpeed/1.3,'',function(){slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');});},(100+time));}else{setTimeout(function(){box.animate({opacity:'1',width:w,height:h},settings.animSpeed/1.3);},(100+time));}})(rows,prevCol,timeBuff,i,totalBoxes);i++;}
prevCol--;}
timeBuff+=100;}}}
var shuffle=function(arr){for(var j,x,i=arr.length;i;j=parseInt(Math.random()*i),x=arr[--i],arr[i]=arr[j],arr[j]=x);return arr;}
var trace=function(msg){if(this.console&&typeof console.log!="undefined")
console.log(msg);}
this.stop=function(){if(!$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop=true;trace('Stop Slider');}}
this.start=function(){if($(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop=false;trace('Start Slider');}}
settings.afterLoad.call(this);return this;};$.fn.nivoSlider=function(options){return this.each(function(key,value){var element=$(this);if(element.data('nivoslider'))return element.data('nivoslider');var nivoslider=new NivoSlider(this,options);element.data('nivoslider',nivoslider);});};$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults={effect:'random',slices:15,boxCols:8,boxRows:4,animSpeed:500,pauseTime:5000,startSlide:0,directionNav:true,directionNavHide:true,controlNav:true,controlNavThumbs:false,controlNavThumbsFromRel:false,controlNavThumbsSearch:'.jpg',controlNavThumbsReplace:'_thumb.jpg',keyboardNav:true,pauseOnHover:true,manualAdvance:false,captionOpacity:0.8,prevText:'Prev',nextText:'Next',beforeChange:function(){},afterChange:function(){},slideshowEnd:function(){},lastSlide:function(){},afterLoad:function(){}};$.fn._reverse = []._reverse||[].reverse;})(jQuery); jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitely a JavaScript problem. The URLs are alright thus there has to be some JavaScript messing up. Because there are tons of JavaScript files and libraries added to Your site/theme I was unable to identify the real problem, but if You turn off the javascript within Your browser and try to click on the pagination links You will see the pagination is working correctly.

I would suggest disabling one JavaScript include after another and refreshing the page (just by commenting out the lines within Your footer, header, or appropriate controllers) and checking the pagination. Finally You should be able to identify the one that causes the problem and we could then lead You to the happy ending.

Comment: Thanks sooo much @shadyyx, it was banner_pack.js which was in my header. That is the script that controls my nivo slider on my home.tpl file... So what I did what move that script into my home.tpl file from my header... And now the links work! I had wondered if it had something to do with JS! Thanks again... Also I know generally you are supposed to put scripts in the header/footer... But I don't think it should hurt being in my home.tpl file do you?

Comment: It won't hurt anything, unless You will want to put the slider to another layouts - there You will have no JS file to make the slider working...Anyway, if the problem is solved, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I am having a big issue now, banner_pack.js for some reason controls my click and enter function on my search bar... So when I move it to the home file it fixes the pagination, but it breaks the search field... So now that's an issue... Any ideas?

Comment: Also I don't see anything in the JS that has anything to do with the search bar.

Comment: So the question is why would banner pack effect the code above?

Comment: Where is the javascript code for pagination? I am running so many different libraries that has to be it. Isn't pagination all ran by that PHP library?

Comment: I can also delete all references to the search script in the seach.tpl and the common.js and it will still work as long as banner pack is active

Comment: I don't know. What is this banner_pack.js about?

Comment: It controls the slider on my frontpage (nivo), however for some reason when I remove it my search click/keydown functions no longer work so I cnanot use search. I can even remove the code for the search bar in my common.js file and my search.tpl file with banner pack when it is active and the search still works, but w/o banner pack the search does not work. However for some reason banner pack is the script breaking my paginatiopn links ONLY on the search pages, the category pages pagination works with the script installed... How is a Javascript file breaking PHP pagination?

Comment: That could be a mystery unless You do a debugging of that JS library...I for sure know that default OpenCart does not have that banner_pack.js and the search is working...And for sure the pagination works without it. So remove that banner pack, repair search and manage the banners for nivo slider differently... I have nothing else to say, sorry, so we should end this debate... If You find out what is the real problem (identify it), post a new question describing the problem and how to solve it... Good luck!